# Angular AUTO alert-dismissible isn't working

Tags: angular, alert, bootstrapping

I'm trying to make the alert AUTO dismissible (after few seconds) working in my angular 5 app but didn't succeed.
Found many threads describing the same symptom, followed their solutions but with no luck in my case. Still didn't figure out what is missing!

HTML:

```
<div id="alert" *ngIf="globalError" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" data-auto-dismiss role="alert">
    <a (click)="clearErrors()" class="close" aria-label="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <span id="alertMsg">{{globalError}}</span>
</div>
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
"bootstrap-auto-dismiss-alert": "^1.0.2",
```

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title...</title>
  <!-- Dev Mode -->
  <!-- base href="/"-->
  <!-- Production Mode -->
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link href="tdf.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link href="tdf.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-auto-dismiss-alert@1.0.2/bootstrap-auto-dismiss-alert.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  
</head>
<body>
  <!-- app-root></app-root-->
  
  <div  class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" data-auto-dismiss role="alert">
    <button class="close" aria-label="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <span id="alertMsg">Im in index yo!</span>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" data-auto-dismiss role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**:
I tried something similar before, updated my index.html as well with different version of scripts that I used

angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
"styles.css",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js", 
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

I'm loading a nested component inside my main app component:

app.component.html:

```html
<tabset>
  <!-- tab heading='User' [active]="true">
   <app-resource-manager></app-resource-manager>
  </tab-->
  <tab>
    <ng-template tabHeading>{{user}}</ng-template>
    <app-resource-manager></app-resource-manager>
  </tab>
  <tab *ngIf="isAdmin">
    <ng-template tabHeading>Admin</ng-template>
    <app-privilege-manager></app-privilege-manager>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: we don't need your `index.html`. Post the component code & Template code

Comment: posted the index.html to share to which bootstrap I'm pointing to. No much code, simply the div alert block above

Comment: @RitwickDey its feature of `BootstrapJS`. Component .`ts` code is irrelevant.

Comment: @Antoniossss, Question is `Angular alert-dismissible isn't working`, so I though he want to control by Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery and BootstrapJS is probably not loaded.

Add this at the end of your `index.html`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can leave CSS inclusing in `index.html` or move it to `angular.json`, `styles` section

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css"
       ,"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
        "scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
           "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

As you can see, there is `scripts` section. Normally you should include here script files from `node_modules` but for some reason it fails to load script bundle (seems like Stackblitz issue) - that is why you have to include `script` tags in `index.html`

Here is working example for you

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fynumd

**EDIT**: Autodismiss works now - using minified form causes troubles. It starts to work if I use non minified version from CDN

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fynumd?file=src%2Findex.html

</app-root-->

×
    Im in index yo!

×
  **Warning!** Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title...</title>
  <!-- Dev Mode -->
  <!-- base href="/"-->
  <!-- Production Mode -->
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link href="tdf.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link href="tdf.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  
</head>
<body>
  <!-- app-root></app-root-->
  
  <div  class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" data-auto-dismiss role="alert">
    <button class="close" aria-label="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <span id="alertMsg">Im in index yo!</span>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" data-auto-dismiss role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>
</body>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-auto-dismiss-alert@1.0.2/bootstrap-auto-dismiss-alert.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Antoniossss. The example that you provided didn't work for me either! Alerts were suppose to be auto-dismissed after 5 seconds (if you don't specify something else) but they didn't.

Comment: No, I didn't include auto-dismiss feature. I have shown you where your trouble is, you can fix it with little effort now.

Comment: I included the script that you gave, still have the same problem. I had tried this before with different scripts that I found in one of the threads. Updated my post with more information. Thanks anyway, will keep trying :)

Comment: And dismiss still does not work? (not auto but after clicking)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough,  my bad... The dismiss by click worked all the time.  My problem is with auto dismiss.

Comment: Well done! I took your example as is and put it into my index.html, I even disabled my app totally -pls see updated index.html in my post- just to make sure... and it still not working for me!!! I'm going nuts :S

Comment: I realized that the real problem is with nested components (added app.component.html to my post)... when loading component inside the main component the auto dismiss still not functioning. From index.html itself it worked

Comment: Its because autodismiss is loaded BEFORE your notifications actually shows. This "library" is simple function that runs on script load, takes every present (at that time) alerts and sets timeouts for them. Since there is no alerts yet....

Comment: I tried moving the scripts inside nested components but didn't help.. any other suggestions? I mean, always the scripts will be loaded before my alerts appears, they appears by *ngIf when there is an error

Comment: Yep, you would have to do that "by hand". I guess it would be easier for you to handle alert dismiss by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since the auto-dismiss script must be loaded after the alert actually apears, it doesn't fit my requierment... so I did somthing easier that I control by code:

```
export class MyComponent {
globalError: string;
isBusy: boolean;

constructor(private service: ResourcesService, private router: Router) {

    service.resourceErrorHandler$.subscribe(value => {
                        this.globalError = value;
                        setTimeout(() => this.globalError = null, 1000);
                        });

    service.busyHandler$.subscribe(value => {
                        this.isBusy = value;
                        });

}
```